# My c program is not calculating decimal values and is just printing whole num

Tags: c, structure

This program is calculating average in whole number without printing decimal values. It prints the result as a whole number: *N.000000*. Why?

```
//Store name, roll no, marks of 4 students using structure
//and calculating average
struct student
{
    char name[10];
    int roll_no;
    int marks;
};

void main()
{
    struct student s1,s2,s3,s4;
    float avg;
    clrscr();
    printf("\nEnter name, rollnumber and marks of student 1 : \n");
    scanf("%s%d%d",&s1. name,&s1. roll_no,&s1. marks);
    printf("\nEnter name, rollnumber and marks of student 2 : \n");
    scanf("%s%d%d",&s2. name,&s2. roll_no,&s2. marks);
    printf("\nEnter name, rollnumber and marks of student 3 : \n");
    scanf("%s%d%d",&s3. name,&s3. roll_no,&s3. marks);
    printf("\nEnter name, rollnumber and marks of student 4 : \n");
    scanf("%s%d%d",&s4. name,&s4. roll_no,&s4. marks);
    avg = (s1. marks + s2. marks + s3. marks + s4. marks) / 4;
    printf("\nAverage : %f",avg);

    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int marks;
```

means that each mark is an integer. Then you sum them, that's also an integer. Then you divide them by 4, that's also an integer, so this operation will be an integer division - an operation that throws away the fractional part of the result. Divide it by `4.0` instead and you'll be fine to go.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> avg = (s1. marks + s2. marks + s3. marks + s4. marks) / 4;
> ```

Since all the marks are integers and 4 is also an integer, the division will follow integer rules - there won't be any decimals to begin with.

Try casting one of the marks to `double` or `float`, or you can add a `.0` after 4.

Comment: It will 'strip the decimals'?  Surely, the whole computation is done in integer arithmetic and the final (integer) result is converted to float.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler What was I thinking :-?

Answer (score 1):

All of the operands in your calculation are `int`, so your result is `int`.

Introduce a float into the calculation to preserve the fractional part of your average:

```
avg = (s1. marks + s2. marks + s3. marks + s4. marks) / 4.0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just divide the sum by 4.0

Code is as below :

```
avg = (s1. marks + s2. marks + s3. marks + s4. marks) / 4.0;
```

This will solve your problem.

---

It is because you have taken marks as an `int` value and also dividing it with `int` value (i.e. 4). So, When you divide both `int` value then the result would be an `int` value. However, when we divide by a `double` value (i.e. 4.0), the result would be calculated in `double` format and then converted to `float` when assigned to `avg`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You're right; it will solve the problem.  But it would be more helpful to explain why it will solve the problem.

Comment: That's a good comment, but it should be in the answer itself.  You're allowed to edit your own answers (and your own questions) regardless of your rep.  I've transferred it for you this time; please do it yourself in future.  You should delete your comment (though I've flagged it to the moderators as 'obsolete'); and I'll try to remember to delete this comment.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.

1. Your student grades are `int` types, which means that when you divide them, add them, or do most operations with them, it will be `int` division, addition, etc, which returns `int`s.
2. Your output statements use `%d` as a formatting directive, which formats the passed value as an int.

To fix the first problem

```
((float)s1.marks) + ...
```

Will cast your `int` to a `float`, and future `ints` added to `floats` yield `floats`.

To fix the second problem

```
printf("... %f ...", value);
```

will format the value as if it were a float (which it should be).

There are other solutions, for example, many financial systems don't wish to deal with fractions of a penny, so the values are stored as counts of the smallest considered fraction, and formatted appropriately as fractional dollars ($11.03 but the stored value is 1103).